# How to statistic character string in one column with R language?

Tags: r, string

I have a table like this

[image]

Now I want statistic the frequency  of k1,k2,k3... in column "keyword". How can I do this.

I want to use package like "string"

The file link [wl.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cg0fat3onxsqrbj/wl.csv?dl=0) (chinese-language)

The file have 500 rows. Each row is a paper. Every paper have 1~3 keywords. I want to statistic the frequency of keyword.

Comment: 1. Post actual code in your questions, not screen shots; 2. What have you tried?; 3. There is no package called "string".

Comment: 1.The file is https://www.dropbox.com/s/cg0fat3onxsqrbj/wl.csv?dl=0  2.I use the "table" to count the frequency,failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need any packages for this. Also, there is no such package as `string`. Were you thinking of `stringr`?

You can use `strsplit`, `table`, and `unlist` to get your frequency count across all observations.

```
df <- data.frame(title=c("A","B","C"),keywords=c("k1;k2;k3","k4;k1","k1;k2"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

list_of_keywords <- strsplit(df$keywords,";")
table(unlist(list_of_keywords))
```

The result will be:

```
k1 k2 k3 k4 
 3  2  1  1
```

Answer (score -1):

If `df` is your dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Title = paste0("title",toupper(letters[1:7])), 
                 keywords = c("k1;k2;k3", "k4;k1", "k1;k2", "k3;k4", "k2", "k5", "k4;k2;k5"))


library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
temp <- df$keywords %>% str_split(";")

# Obtain the frequency by flattening the list and using the table function
table(unlist(temp))
```